# Xamarin Forms Open Image in another app

Tags: xamarin.forms

I'm using xamarin forms. All I need to do is to open Image full sized with zooming and dragging. I know, that on Android I could do it using another app, "Gallery" for example.
But what should I do when developing on cross platform apps? Maybe there is a lib, that can do such things?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the solution for my issue a long time ago, but forget about the answer.
For me the solution was to use the [Stormlion Photo Browser](https://github.com/stormlion227/PhotoBrowser.Forms). It has some nice functionality, and works with local images. For Uri you just need to use `"file:///your_path_to_image"` and that's it!

Answer (score 0):

Take a look on [ImageEdit](https://github.com/muak/Xamarin.Plugin.ImageEdit) plugin. It supports Xamarin.iOS and Xamarin.Android platforms.

> This plugin will enable you to manipulate(resize,crop,rotate,monochrome) a image(png,jpg).